# How to Output CSV and Tab Delimited files With Different Fields in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to output two separate data outputs in SSRS 2008 R2 from the report server with different columns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Frank. What do you mean by "two separate data outputs"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627537%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

We currently have two extensions (csv and tab delimited) that use the "Data renderer" which means they receive their structure from "DateElement" properties on report items.  I want to have different fields and field layout on two separate "Data renderer" outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could investigate using XSLT to transform the XML output into a desired format. This is really the only option I know of, other than making another bespoke report with the actual output you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159716(v=sql.90).aspx

(Probably more up to date links out there, just Google/Bing "SSRS XSLT" etc)

Comment: That's what I was coming to on subsequent research as well.  Thanks.  It loooks like that's the route to go.